# Embedded image in SendGrid email

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sendgrid

I am managing to send mails just fine with send grid, attachment too no issues. But I am having problems embedding images into the body of the HTML mail

Here is the code that I am using, put together after reading various examples on this issue. Anyone know where I am going wrong, regards...

```
        MemoryStream msLogo = new MemoryStream(obj.logo);
        Bitmap b = new Bitmap(msLogo);
        ImageConverter ic = new ImageConverter();
        Byte[] ba = (Byte[])ic.ConvertTo(b, typeof(Byte[]));
        MemoryStream logo = new MemoryStream(ba);

        AlternateView htmlView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(sBody, null, "text/html");

        LinkedResource imageResource = new LinkedResource(logo);


        var imagelink = new LinkedResource(logo, "image/png");
        imagelink.ContentId = string.Format("logo", myMessage);
        imagelink.TransferEncoding = TransferEncoding.Base64;
        b.Save(logo, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        logo.Position = 0;
```

Comment: It's worth noting that [SendGrid generally discourages embedding images](https://sendgrid.com/blog/embedding-images-emails-facts/).

Comment: Are you adding the `LinkedResource` to the `AlternateView` anywhere? And then are you adding the `AlternateView` to the message?